# How to separate variables in list: return alphanumeric or numeric values

Tags: python, database, dataframe, data-science, data-cleaning

From a certain df I extracted the columns and have doubts on how to proceed according this post title.

```
df_example = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\example.csv")
df = df_example.columns
df_numerics_only = df.select_dtypes(include=np.number)
print (df_numerics_only)
```

and got the following error:

> AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: Can you provide an example content of `example.csv`?

Comment: @Henfu can you confirm which SciPy libraries you're using here?  I've tagged the question with pandas and numpy tags in case you are.

Answer (score 0):

Your line 2 is just storing column names in the variable `df`.
`df` is not a dataframe here and hence `select_dtypes()` throws error.

Just remove the second line and call select_dtypes() on your dataframe.

```
df_example = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\example.csv")
df_numerics_only = df_example.select_dtypes(include=np.number)
print (df_numerics_only)
```